# A red arrow problem on codelite using the mac that is unable to be solved by unchecking the diagnostic box

Tags: c++, macos, c++17, codelite

Can't Find the Diagnostic Box to uncheck. This is seen in the instructions of `'Select 'Plugins'->' Language Server'->'Settings'` and uncheck the box that says 'Display Diagnostics' at the bottom of the page then click OK.

However, I just can't find the 'Display Diagnostics' part in the Language server settings. I have attached an image showing the language server settings that pop up on my computer. If anyone can fix this, please respond to this inquiry. Thanks a lot.

(btw Thx Girish for editing this for me)

[image: Settings View]

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) your question and improve your question clearly indicating what your problem is.

Comment: IMO, you can ask directly on Codelite forum.